# How to stop container within itself?

Tags: docker

I am experimenting to let container terminate itself (for example, when it detects exception). But shutdown seems not working. Here is what I run inside the container.

```
$ sudo shutdown -h now
shutdown: Unable to shutdown system

Broadcast message from ...

The system is going down for halt NOW!
```

When hitting "Enter", it comes back.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container stops once the entrypoint exits. If you entered in interactive mode just do ctrl + D.

Comment: The last command of docker is "sleep infinity", and I get into the container using "docker exec". In such case, "Ctrl-d" doesn't work. :(